# How to use back button or navigation in app?

Tags: navigation, app, back-button

How do you decide the navigation method to use, whether backwards or hierarchy navigation?

For example, users are navigating on the app, and they received a push notification which leads them to open the inbox page. When they click the back button, do we lead users back to the page where they are viewing previously, or based on the page hierarchy?

If we use backwards navigation, does it means the app must remember all the actions the users did?

Comment: I think this is related to you query: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/111941/back-button-on-mobile-application?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Since the back button has no preview option, the user should be able to easily get back to the item, if the back button does not meet his expectations. So if the hierarchy is really big, you should probably provide the user with a history of all his visited items, where he can easily go back to any item he visited.

If the user presses a notification and was already working in the app on another item, the back button should bring him back to that item. If he was not working in the app, you can default to climbing up the hierarchy.